# How to create a large object (CLOB) in a HSQLDB resource database?

Tags: jpa, hsqldb, clob

I have created a HSQLDB (version 2.3.3) database preloaded with data and bundled it up as a resource (db.properties and db.script) to be used by automated tests where I do not need the data generated by the tests to be saved back to disk.  This works fine for most of the JPA entities I have (all CRUD operations work as expected).  However, I have two entities that include a column annotated with '@Lob' where I cannot create new entities because HSQLDB fails saying 'the table data is read only'.

I've read through the documentation about [Large Objects](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html) but it doesn't describe the behaviour when using a resource database.  I'm guessing HSQLDB is trying to create 'db.lobs' but it can't because effectively files_readonly=true.

Does anyone know if it is possible to create an entity with a 'large object' column with a HSQLDB resource database?

The stack trace is:

```
WARN 12-09-2016 00:57:26 - SQL Error: -458, SQLState: S1000
ERROR 12-09-2016 00:57:26 - org.hsqldb.HsqlException: The table data is read only
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1338)
    ..app classes...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1335)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: The table data is read only
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: The table data is read only
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SessionData.allocateLobForResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.allocateResultLob(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.performPreExecute(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: The table data is read only
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.LobManager.setCharsForNewClob(Unknown Source)
    ... 46 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
```

The code I am running looks like this:

```
    @Test
public void testCreateUserSettings() throws Exception {

    MyDatabase db = MyDatabaseFactory.createMyDatabase("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db1;sql.syntax_ora=true", new Properties());
    //MyDatabase db = MyDatabaseFactory.getMyDatabase("jdbc:hsqldb:res:/my-db-base");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(db.getConnectionProperties());
    properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.provider", "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider");

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("InMemorySeederPU", properties);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    try {
        Date now = new Date();
        String defaultData = "{\"key\": \"value\"}";
        String defaultId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String userId = "uA1";

        UserSetting setting = new UserSetting();
        setting.setIdObject(defaultId);
        setting.setDateCreate(now);
        setting.setDateUpdate(now);
        setting.setDateArrive(now);
        setting.setIdDatabase("A");
        setting.setIdUserCreate(userId);
        setting.setIdUserUpdate(userId);
        setting.setIdOwner(userId);
        setting.setNamespace(defaultId);
        setting.setEntityVersion(1L);
        setting.setData(defaultData);
        setting.setEtag(DigestUtils.md5Hex(defaultData));

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(setting);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        UserSetting setting2 = em.find(UserSetting.class, defaultId);
        Assert.assertEquals(setting2, setting);
    }
    finally {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

MyDatabase is just a wrapper to get a connection to a database. If I use 'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:...' the test works fine (the createMyDatabase() method loads the in-memory database with the data I need).  However, if I replace that with the commented-out line that uses 'jdbc:hsqldb:res:...' then the test fails and HSQLDB reports the exception 'The table data is read only'.

Putting Hibernate into DEBUG mode shows the following:

```
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:22 - Initializing EntityManagerFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry@59ce792e
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:22 - Registering EntityManagerFactory: InMemorySeederPU 
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - begin
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - Obtaining JDBC connection
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - Obtained JDBC connection
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - initial autocommit status: false
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - Generated identifier: d6d16b01-0181-4f2b-9e5f-2dac0bb097b1, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - Processing flush-time cascades
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - Dirty checking collections
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - Listing entities:
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - com.ben.entity.UserSetting{data={"key": "value"}, dateArrive=Mon Sep 12 16:46:23 AEST 2016, idDatabase=A, idObject=d6d16b01-0181-4f2b-9e5f-2dac0bb097b1, idUserDelete=null, dateCreate=Mon Sep 12 16:46:23 AEST 2016, entityVersion=1, dateUpdate=Mon Sep 12 16:46:23 AEST 2016, idUserCreate=uA1, namespace=d6d16b01-0181-4f2b-9e5f-2dac0bb097b1, etag=88bac95f31528d13a072c05f2a1cf371, idUserUpdate=uA1, idOwner=uA1, dateDelete=null}
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - insert into user_settings (data, date_arrive, date_create, date_delete, date_update, entity_version, etag, id_database, id_owner, id_user_create, id_user_delete, id_user_update, namespace, id_object) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG 12-09-2016 16:46:23 - could not execute statement [n/a]
java.sql.SQLException: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: The table data is read only
```

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: you get an exception but don't state the SQL/DDL being invoked! HSQLDB does support the CLOB JDBC type

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Neil.  I have updated the description with code that illustrates the problem.  I understand that HSQLDB supports CLOB, it just doesn't seem to work when using a resource database (jdbc:hsqldb:res).

Comment: The connection URLs are "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db1;sql.syntax_ora=true" for the test that works and "jdbc:hsqldb:res:/my-db-base" for the resource database that throws the exception.

Comment: I've added debug logging from Hibernate, and the SQL is a straightforward insert statement: insert into user_settings (...) values (...)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HSQLDB manual](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html),

> A res: catalog consists of the files for a small, **read-only** database
>   that can be stored inside a Java resource such as a ZIP or JAR archive
>   and distributed as part of a Java application program.

Consequently you cannot insert data into such a database, and the exception is expected

Comment: HSQLDB res databases do allow you to insert data, it's just that the data cannot be persisted permanently to disk (i.e. any inserted data is lost when the database is shutdown).  The problem is specific to LOBs, but I just noticed there is a statement in the documentation saying 'It is not possible to create new LOBs in these catalogs, but you can use existing LOBs in new rows.'

Comment: If it allows you to insert data then I suggest that you raise an issue on HSQLDB to improve their documentation to clarify this. Saying "read-only" is pretty explicit, and if they really mean "read-only, but modifiable in memory, but not writable" then it should state that.

Answer (score 0):

From the section [RES and Files Readonly Databases](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html):

> There is another option which allows MEMORY tables to be writeable, but without persisting the changes at SHUTDOWN. This option is activated with the property, value pair, files_readonly=true, which can be added to the .properties file of the database, or included in the URL of the first connection to the database.
>
> A res: catalog, is a set of database files on the classpath (inside a
> jar or alongside class files). The database is opened with a URL in
> the form of jdbc:hsqldb:res:. These databases are
> always files_readonly and have the same restrictions as files_readonly
> file: catalogs.
>
> **CACHED tables and LOBS in these catalogs are readonly. It is not
> possible to create new LOBs in these catalogs, but you can use
> existing LOBs in new rows**.